# What is the total height of the 'Extended app bar' along with the 'tabs' in the picture below?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-appbarlayout

Can anybody please tell me what is the total height of the '**Extended app bar**' along with the '**tabs**' in the picture below:

[image]

Is it '`128dp`' or more than it?

Please let me know.

Sorry for bad format of the question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this should be in the material design specs.

Comment: The area that says Page title?

Comment: @TimCastelijns pls see the edited question

Comment: You have asked many questions while only accepting an answer on 1 of them. Please give this a quick read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for future reference

Comment: I'll try & accept this after some time. Sorry, if this hurt you.

Comment: I am not hurt, i'm not talking about this question, but more about all of your questions in general.if someone takes the time to answer your question, and that answer solves your problem, you should accept that answer. How and why is explained in that link.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is the default material setup:

- [The toolbar where the search and overflow icon are is 56dp high](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar)
- [The page title is 80dp high](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-keylines-spacing)
- [The tabs are 48dp high](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html#tabs-specs)

184dp in total.